# Battery life after replacing the motherboard

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

I have an HP EliteBook 840 G5 notebook. After replacing the motherboard by an authorized service center, I have a problem that the device lasts me a half the time on the battery than before the replacement. Also, I don't see a slider on the battery option, which was used to switch power modes.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

[image]

Comment: Contact the service center and ask what happened during the repair.

Comment: Likely some power settings in the BIOS have been defaulted to off. Have a look in the BIOS for power-related options.